# Java list default implementation?

Tags: java, arraylist

If I declare a new list like this:

```
List<String> listExample = someFunction();
```

what list interface implementation will be used?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers so far. What is considered as the clean way to do this, should I always declare list with new?

Comment: That entirely depends on what `someFunction()` returns.

Comment: Invoke `getClass()` on `listExample` and find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Eran commented that totally depends on what `someFunction();` returns .Both `ArrayList<E>` and LinkedList implements List interface .

You can try ,

```
System.out.println("" + listExample.getClass());
```

to find out the which has been implemented. From [`docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()),

```
public final Class<?> getClass()
```

> Returns the runtime class of this Object. The returned Class object is
>   the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the
>   represented class.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are building e.g. LinkedList, ArrayList, Vector, Stack in  and returning from `someFunction()` will be implemented with `listexample`. If you are using List interface reference, it has one benefit, that you can assign any type of object to it (LinkedList, ArrayList, Vector, Stack).

Answer (score 0):

eg if u give 
List listExample = new ArrayList();
Then the Object will be created for ArrayList  and list is just an instance of listExample.

and you can use getClass() for that listExample to view

Comment: I think you're answering a different question than he asked.